# What's the most efficient way to listen for keyboard hits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, listener

I need to listen to the users keyboard presses, to activate some of the shortcuts in my app (when the user presses the key "H" it hides some part of the app, etc). I also need to listen for the shift key or even the alt key to have a more versatile shortcut system.

This is what I have so far:

```
window.onkeyup = (e) => { keys[e.keyCode] = false; keyRelease(e.keyCode) }
window.onkeydown = (e) => { keys[e.keyCode] = true; keyPress(e.keyCode) }
```

```
function keyPress(key) {

  switch (key) {
    case 37:
      //left

      break;
    case 39:
      //right
      break;

    case 80:
     // p
     if (keys[16]){
      //shift key is also being pressed
     // do stuff
     }

    default:
    // code block
  }
}
```

It works fine, but it I feel like its not efficient and there should be a better way to do this, and not having to searching for each key's code (which btw in some browsers and OS are different). Keep in mind I have to add around 30 shortcut combinations. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There's a lot of codes to check, keycodes are different, and on all of that [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated. Use [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead. Store the code for the short-cut actions in methods of an object and name the methods by the keys. Then checking the pressed keys and calling the correct method should be trivial.

Comment: As @Teemu mentioned, there is indeed a lot of different things consider. If you plan to use it for a lot of shortcuts in your app, I'd rather suggest using a full-fledged library. I used this one a while ago and it was good https://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: I agree. The statement "It works fine, but it feels like its not efficient..", basically cries for using a library.

Comment: @AlexBuznik thank you for your recommendation this library fits my needs perfectly